# unfortunately camera has stopped

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm using AVD with Android 4.2 installed. The AVD has this configuration: [image: screenchot]

When I click on the Camera app, I get the following error message: `unfortunately camera has stopped.`

I tried to clear data from the camera but that did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: You should be able to get the LogCat errors which will help you track the problem down.

Comment: @StilesCrisis Sure it is.  He's probably trying to mock the camera on the virtual device with a webcam

Comment: The log: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7A7LL.png and the last lines http://i.stack.imgur.com/TN0t3.png

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check the logcat from when the emulator boots up to see if it is detecting your webcam correctly; you can also try to run the emulator directly from the commandline with the -d camera option to receive extra camera debugging messages.

To simplify the issue, try switching to the fake emulator camera instead of the webcam; this will produce a simple checkerboard testing image.