# Camera has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse, camera, android-virtual-device

I have a big problem!

When I want to start camera in Eclipse AVD android emulator it shows `Unfortunately, Camera has stopped`. When I start App Camera - light near my laptop camera turns on, but just for a few seconds. It turns off when I click at error communicate "OK". I have Lenovo B590 laptop. I've updated my drivers. My camera works in Skype. I tried running my AVD with another target and another CPU(atom etc), but still same error.

I tried all solutions for my problem from this site (and another), but none worked. I need to write the program, but I can't test it when the camera doesn't work.

Screenshot with my AVD settings:

[image]

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276450/how-to-use-web-camera-in-android-emulator-to-capture-a-live-image

Comment: I tryed it yet. I read all topics from this site.

Comment: Duplicate of question which was closed by community.

[unfortunately-camera-has-stopped][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244505/unfortunately-camera-has-stopped

Comment: Maybe my problem need other way to solve? Here is log from CatLog: http://speedy.sh/ahxvG/log.txt

Answer (score 0):

1. According to me, first of all check your system drivers and calculate how many drivers are not present in system or not updated or which are outdated via driver max or update my driver software then install/update web camera,usb bus related, memory related, chip-set related and port and processor related drivers install(you can install the driver by CD when ever you purchase your computer at that time some shoppers are given that)
2. Then edit your AVD back camera value `set=webcame0` and give the size of your SD card and memory then click edit and then ok and run you camera application. I'm sure that camera will start.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on an Lenovo X220. I solved it by installing a "fake-cam" driver.